# Does the stackapps API allow queries of question to get answers?

Tags: support

All of the API docs I've seen are just for getting metadata, stuff like "how many comments".

Is there an API to ask questions?

eg here: I can't see a way to add a query string:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers

there is some `q` param:

`q - a free form text parameter, will match all question properties based on an undocumented algorithm.`

/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&q=is bitcoin anonymous&site=stackoverflow

I did try a test question using that, but the results are all over the place and don't even mention the search terms in many places.

Update: possibly it's just the API uses an old search algorithm, different from the site.

[How do you trigger the search/advanced 'q' parameter to search all words?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3871/how-do-you-trigger-the-search-advanced-q-parameter-to-search-all-words)

Then I need to combine with these fields, and add `++` to terms to force a boolean include.

- q - a free form text parameter, will match all question properties based on an undocumented algorithm.
- body - text which must appear in returned questions' bodies.
- title - text which must appear in returned questions' titles.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an API to ask questions?

If you mean creating a new question, yes: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question. You do need an [access token with write access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write).

> Does the stackapps API allow queries of question to get answers?

That looks more like you're searching for the answers to a single question: this is possible as well, either with https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions or (with the appropriate [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters)) with https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids.